# Real Time data collection - Help select Database

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation, nosql

My Scenario:

I want to collect data from various sensors[for now I have 600 sensors sending data, but this may have to scale up to 3000 more data sensors, all sensors send real time data] Now I have to run network based queries on this data, the data does not have to be in the database for a long time, as I query I have to make calculations based on the current state of the sensors. I do not need historic data. There would be multiple queries made to the database.

My requirements are;

A real time database that is quick. Scalability is an issue , but can be overlooked as I exactly know how many sensors would send data. Large number of queries on the DB. This is an academic project so my preferences are to open source.

I am not a database person , and the shear number of selections that there are is overwhelming. Any help and suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: How often will data come in from each sensor?

Comment: For now each sensor checks for changes very 800 millisecond.But i have the liberty to tune the sensors to a maximum of 1200 milliseconds.

Comment: Wouldn't simple memcache fit your bill ?